# Help reduce site load-time. How can I cut down this resource?

Tags: optimization, resources, load, indexing

[image: Index resource takes up half of page load time]
My index resource takes up half my sites load time. Google got it down to just about 30-50 ms, how would I go about achieving this?

Also, how can I parallelize the downloading of my images. They all wait for the previous one to load before starting to load, any way to fix this?

Thanks!
~ Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you geographically located in relative proximity to the server this page is hosted on? If not, then the long wait time you're looking at (before the darker shade of blue, where data is actually being transferred) is bound to be longer. Since it's the first document served to you, a connection between the server and your computer first has to be established, the length of which depends on that proximity, along with the server's responsiveness (is it a high-load server? are pages created dynamically?).

Google has many, many servers placed strategically around the globe to ensure fast-loading pages for just about everybody; you can't compete with that, but what you can do is make sure you're hosting in a location nearest to where most of your audience is located.

As for the parallelization of downloads, you can achieve this by spreading your static resources across several hostnames (e.g. static1.example.com, static2.example.com, etc). Google has a good write-up about this recommendation for pages that serve a lot of static resources, particularly images: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#ParallelizeDownloads

Comment: It's just on my localhost, it isn't even ing from anywhere, it's a virtual server, my HD.

Comment: Then a comparison with Google is practically pointless, considering you're testing their servers live on the web, and your own locally. I cannot read the full graph, only what you've posted, but from what I've seen when loading pages from my own hard drive, I can tell that when the resource is not pulled from the cache, the 'transfer' begins immediately (i.e. there is no lighter shade of blue in the graph, only dark). If, however, that same resource is pulled from the browser cache, there is a bit of latency, caused in all likelihood by the browser retrieving the file from its cache.

Answer (score 1):

Check [zbugs.com](http://zbugs.com) Try optimizing the images, js and css.

Also checkout [Yahoo Practices guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).